# Extract Pairwise Correlation from Correlation Matrix in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to extract the pairwise correlation (e.g. pearson) into a spark dataframe. I want to use the pairwise coreelation in table format in further queries and as machine learning input.

So here is a running example:

**Data:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, Row, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// rdd
    val rowsRdd: RDD[Row] = sc.parallelize(
      Seq(
        Row(2.0, 7.0, 1.0),
        Row(3.5, 2.5, 0.0),
        Row(7.0, 5.9, 0.0)
      )
    )

// Schema  
    val schema = new StructType()
      .add(StructField("item_1", DoubleType, true))
      .add(StructField("item_2", DoubleType, true))
      .add(StructField("item_3", DoubleType, true))

// Data frame  
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(rowsRdd, schema)
```

**Correlation Matrix**

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

   val rows = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(df.columns).setOutputCol("corr_features")
      .transform(df)
      .select("corr_features")
      .rdd
   val items_mllib_vector = rows.map(_.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector](0))
                             .map(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.fromML)

   val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(items_mllib_vector, "pearson")
```

The output is the correlation matrix of all elements. I would like to extract pairwise each element (i:j) with the correlation coefficent and the name of each element into a dataframe.

Needed output:

```
item_from | item_to | Correlation
item_1    | item_2  | -0.0096912
item_1    | item_3  | -0.7313071
item_2    | item_3  | 0.68910356
```

Comment: Anyone any advice for me? How Would you build a loop to extract Name and Correlation for each position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help I was able to find a solution:

Get the  result into a local Array:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val pairwiseArr = new ListBuffer[Array[Double]]()

for( i <- 0 to correlMatrix.numRows-1){
  for(j <- 0 to correlMatrix.numCols-1){
    pairwiseArr += Array(i, j, correlMatrix.apply(i,j))
  }
}
```

Transform the Array into a spark Dataframe:

```
case class pairRow(i: Double, j: Double, corr: Double)

val pairwiseDF = pairwiseArr.map(x => pairRow(x(0), x(1), x(2))).toDF()
display(pairwiseDF
```

)

Since the Array is a local one it's preferred to use [ColumnSimilarities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607499/get-column-names-after-columnsimilarties-spark-scala)